# flat price for 6 items then price per additional

Tags: shipping

trying to figure out how to do the following

> if customer buys up to 6 tubes the shipping cost is flat rated at 8.25 and every additional after 6 is .25 cents

for usa customers

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to setup tables with condition set to #of items vs destination. This can be found in `system>configuration>sales>shipping method>table rates`.

Comment: well i seen some examples of the table rates can you send me a example ?

Comment: can i do the following one for the usa, and one for canada and one for other countries?